# Weird Arrow elbems showing up in Caja

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate, symbolic-link, colors, ls

Wierd Arrow emblems are showing up in Caja, also in ls in Terminal these directory are  highlighted light blue, but it seems that they are not a link at all.
Output of ls:

[image: click here because i have less than 10 rep]

Gui:

[image: click here becuase i have less than 10 rep]

I'm using Ubuntu MATE 22.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are soft links (`man ln`). Do: `ls -l /` to see details (`man ls ls_colors`).

Comment: OK. Please as a reminder, comments are not for Extended Discussion